# Suggested edit comment width is too narrow

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

A suggested edit is accompanied by a comment. This comment is displayed when reviewing it from within the Suggested Edits Review Queue:

[image]

If the comment is lengthy, the line-wrapping is truncated.

<sub>Using Google Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m.</sub>